# Return array length instead of elements in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

I want to be able to specify in my MongoDB query to, for each document, return the number of elements in a specific sub field (`var_2` in this case), instead of the whole array. Example document:

```
{
  "_id": "abc123",
  "var_1": "A",
  "var_2": [
    "A", 
    "B", 
    "C"
  ]
}
```

I have tried this but it returns the whole array:

```
db.collection.find({var_1: "A"}, {var_1: 1, var_2: 1})
```

Desired output:

```
{
"_id": "abc123",
"var_1": "A",
"var_2": 3
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the size of your array by using `$size` but with an aggregation since it's not supported in find' projection:

```js
db.your_collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      var_1: "A"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "var_1": 1,
      "var_2": {
        "$size": "$var_2"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

> Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "abc123",
    "var_1": "A",
    "var_2": 3
  }
]
```